# Can I keep the my pig scripts and shell scripts in aws EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr, amazon-emr

I have worked in cloudera Box and I put all my scripts in edge node. I am new to EMR in aws ,so I need ur suggestion.

What I have done.

1.I have logged into master node By ssh using putty.
2. Created folders where I put all my scripts.

I have read some article to put the scripts in s3. But May I know is there any problem going with the approach, I have mentioned.

Do I need stand up an ec2 linux , where I can put these scripts and call emr jobs from that ec2 box.

Need ur view.

Sanjeeb

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have taken is correct. We have scripts on EMR master node as well as S3. The advantage of having on S3 is that, if EMR crashes, you have scripts on S3. Additionally, if you are executing from multiple EMR's, having the script on S3 makes it easier to invoke it from S3 itself instead of copying to each EMR instance.

You can invoke pig scripts from S3 using sh -c 'pig -f ..'

There is no point in having additional ec2 running just to invoke the jobs.

How are you calling your emr jobs?

Comment: I have a ec2 windows running .From source I am getting xlx files.from Windows cli I have executing .bat file (contains aws s3 cp , vb script to coonvert xlx to csv, them emr script for DQ and transformation and them copy commands). These .bat scripts is in window ec2 now. Everything is running fine but I need to get rid of windows scripting because I am unix guy. I don't know how to schedule these jobs. EMR scripting is kicked by pig -f files input= output=.

Comment: You can schedule them using Cron. You can also use python to schedule them - something like apscheduler. `sh -c` is invoking shell script just like `sh test.sh`. You can invoke pig script that is in S3 using `pig -f s3://bucket-name/pig_script.pig`